# If$\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges absolutely, then $\sum\frac{1}{|x-a_n|} $ converges uniformly on closed, bounded intervals not containing any $a_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been thinking about this problem for a while, but the only method I have considered is attempting to use the comparison test for uniform convergence by showing that $$\frac{1}{|x-a_n|}\leq b_n$$ for all $n$, where $b_n$ is something that converges uniformly. However, I don't think I have enough information to apply this test. Any alternate method suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the convergence of the series we have that $|a_n|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore given a bounded interval $I$ there esists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have that for every $x\in I$ it holds $|a_n|\geq 2|x|$, which gives
$$|x-a_n|\geq |a_n|-|x|\geq \frac{|a_n|}{2}$$
and so
$$\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{|x-a_n|}\leq 2\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{|a_n|}$$
from which the uniform convergence follows.

Comment: Clear and concise argument, thanks much.